# Spreadsheet Gear returning Empty cells

Tags: c#, excel, null, spreadsheetgear

I've created a program that returns specific columns from an Excel File through Spreadsheet Gear. Here is my While Loop:

```
     while (Worksheet.Cells[ExcelRow, 1].Value != null)
     { //to do code here
     }
```

When null, my code returns empty cells of rows - even though I specified here not to.

It returns 0 for all cells that are empty in the data grid. Is there a way not display cells that are empty in the Excel File?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can determine the used cells using the SpreadsheetGear API. Try using:

```
    IWorksheet.UsedRange
```

[SpreadsheetGear Reference](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/help/spreadsheetgear.net.4.0/SpreadsheetGear~SpreadsheetGear.IWorksheet~UsedRange.html)

This will return the used portion of the spreadsheet as an IRange.